# I want to add a variable into mysql in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I insert a record in the database like this

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO xtable (x_date, x_time, x_text) VALUES ('2018-05-26', '23:00:00', 'blablabla')";
 connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
    connection.end();
  });
});
```

The above works but lets say I do

```
 var ytime = '19:00:00';
 var ydate = '2018-05-29';
 var ytext = 'blabla';

 connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO xtable (x_date, x_time, x_text) VALUES (ydate, ytime, ytext)";
 connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
    connection.end();
  });
});
```

How do I do that? this gives just errors my node is v8.10.0

Comment: in sql query string there are not values but only the strings itself. so you will need to plug the values of the variables in your sql query

Answer (score 0):

The latter didn't work because the sql statement did not interpret your ydate,ytime,ytext as variables but as a part of string. If you want to separate the statement and your data, you should do like this:

```
var ytime = '19:00:00';
 var ydate = '2018-05-29';
 var ytext = 'blabla';
 var sql = "INSERT INTO xtable (x_date, x_time, x_text) VALUES (?,?,?)";
 connection.query(sql, [ydate,ytime, ytext], function(err,result) {
...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You just switch your data to use [placeholder values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries), then add the data separately:

```
connection.query(
  "INSERT INTO xtable (x_date, x_time, x_text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 
  [ ydate, ytime, ytext ],
  function (err, result) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

One thing to note about Node and MySQL is there's tools like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) that make this a lot easier. Anything that supports Promises and `async`/`await` is almost always less fuss than a series of nested callbacks.